# MANIFEST.MF Attributes returning null

Tags: java, attributes, manifest

I'm trying to get a few attributes from a MANIFEST.MF file, but they return null.

**MANIFEST**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver 
Built-By: jenkins 
Build-Time: 2016-04-09T18:02:46Z Class-Path: spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9 
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77

Name: Build Details 
Implementation-SCM-Revision: SomeCommit 
Implementation-Build-Number: SomeBuildNumber 
Implementation-Title: SomeTitle 
Implementation-Version: 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

**Code** (This code isn't the exact code used, but is almost the same)

First try

```
 public void doStuff() {
    String version;
    InputStream stream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            properties.load(stream);

            version = properties.getProperty("Implementation-SCM-Revision"); //This is null 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //TODO handle exception
        }
    }
```

Second try

```
public void doStuff() {
    Enumeration resEnum;
    try {
        resEnum = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
        while (resEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                URL url = (URL)resEnum.nextElement();
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
                    Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                    String version = mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-SCM-Revision"); //This is null
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that when all the keys from Attributes#getMainAttributes() get printed, it prints `[Archiver-Version, Implementation-Title, Sealed, Specification-Version, Implementation-Version, Created-By, Manifest-Version, Build-Jdk, Specification-Vendor, Implementation-Vendor, Ant-Version, Specification-Title, Built-By, Main-Class]`, it excludes the things like `Implementation-SCM-Revision`. That is the one I'm trying to get.

No stacktrace is generated, it just prints `null` in the console when printing the `Implementation-SCM-Revision` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Oracle managed to break the Manifest class even though it was hard:
[JDK-8201636 null value when trying to read manifest file attributes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8201636)

See also similar bug for MANIFEST entires:
[JDK-8031748 Clarify jar entry orders in a jar file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031748):

> From the beginning, the jar file has an “undocumented” assumption that
> the MANIFEST.MF file and signature-related files (block and SF) should
> appear at the beginning (except for directory entries, say,
> META-INF/).

Answer (score 0):

The [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519430/7525132) is wrong. While the bug reports it mentions are not unrelated, there is a clear error in the code provided in the question. Therefore, it does not provide wrong information, but it indicates a wrong conclusion.

---

The attribute `Implementation-SCM-Revision` is not a main attribute but an attribute of the manifest entry `Build Details`.

Simplified, a manifest has the following form

```yaml
# fixed
Manifest-Version: 1.0

# Main Attributes
Implementation-Version: 1.0

# 'Name:' marks the beginning of an entry
Name: com.example.Foo
# all following lines belong to the previously started entry
# this line therefore applies to com.example.Foo
Checksum: 76652367792347
```

Therefore, to retrieve the value of `Implementation-SCM-Revision`, one must do

```
manifest.getAttributes("Build Details").getValue("Implementation-SCM-Revision");
```

The other way round, in order for `Implementation-SCM-Revision` to be retrieved via `manifest.getMainAttributes()`, it would have to be above `Name:`

```yaml
Manifest-Version: 1.0
# other main attributes
Implementation-SCM-Revision: SomeCommit
Name: Build Details
# other entry-related attributes
```